# Angular Property '$ref' is missing in type 'AngularFireList<{}>

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, angular2-services

i got this error

> /Users/macmini/Desktop/newap/src/app/component/content/content.component.ts (18,5): Type 'AngularFireList<{}>' is not assignable to type 'FirebaseListObservable'.
>
> Property '$ref' is missing in type 'AngularFireList<{}>'.

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Subscription} from 'rxjs';

import {AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import {FirebaseListObservable} from 'angularfire2/database-deprecated';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})

export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  courses$:FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;

  constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
    this.courses$ = db.list('/courses');

  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let item of (courses$ | async)">
  <li><a href="#">{{item.$value}}</a>

  </li>
</ul>
```

app-modal

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {AngularFireModule} from 'angularfire2'
import {AngularFireDatabaseModule} from 'angularfire2/database'
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ContentComponent } from './component/content/content.component';




@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ContentComponent,

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

package.ison

```
{
  "name": "newap",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "firebase": "^4.7.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "xjs": "^0.1.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.0.4",
    "tslint": "~5.3.2",
    "typescript": "~2.3.3"
  }
}
```

i use version angular and nodejs 
@angular/cli: 1.1.0
node: 8.11.2
os: darwin x64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the problem is related to the fact that you're using a deprecated method of accessing list data. Refer to [this link for the relevant Angularfire2 documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md) on accessing lists.

It provides this example that doesn't use a `FirebaseListObservable`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of items | async">
       {{ item | json }}
    </li>
  </ul>
  `,
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.items = db.list('items').valueChanges();
  }

}
```

Comment: i use angular2    version : 1.1.0   node: 8.11.2      os: darwin x64

Comment: The important package here is the Angularfire2 package... not your Angular CLI version, not your Node version, and definitely not your OS. Adjust your code in your TypeScript and HTML files so that it isn't using the deprecated parts of Angularfire2 and you shouldn't receive that error anymore.

Comment: thank you for your answer i appreciate your effort ,

Comment: i would like to look to this issue it`s also relate by observable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841487/angular-2-property-push-does-not-exist-on-type-observable