# angular 2 Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable'

Tags: angular, firebase, observable

I am having a problem with push data

component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-content',
  templateUrl: './content.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./content.component.css']
})

export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  courses$:Observable<any[]>;

  authors$:Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
    this.courses$ = db.list('/courses').valueChanges();
    this.authors$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();

  }
  add(course:HTMLInputElement){
    this.courses$.push(course.value);
    course.value = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

html 
i put input to get the put the input

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="add()">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of courses$ | async">
    {{ item | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

ERROR

content.component.ts (25,19): Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Do you want to update some data in your FireBase DB? the push() method is used for Arrays - not observables.

Comment: it`s not update it is push to database new data

Comment: If you want to "push" to the db, you should us the `put()` method.

Answer (score 2):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    courses$;
    courseObservable;
    authors$;
    constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
        this.courseObservable = db.list('/courses');
        this.courses$ = this.courseObservable.valueChanges();
        this.authors$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();

    }
    add(course: HTMLInputElement) {
        this.courseObservable.push(course.value);
        course.value = '';
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" (keyup.enter)="add()">
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of courses$ | async">
    {{ item | json }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because observables are not arrays, you can't push new data to them. You want something like this where you subscribe to database changes.

```
  export class ContentComponent implements OnInit {

  courses:Array<any>;

  authors$:Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(db:AngularFireDatabase){
    db.list('/courses').valueChanges().subscribe(res => this.courses = res);
    this.authors$ = db.object('/authors/1').valueChanges();

  }
  add(course:HTMLInputElement){
    this.courses.push(course.value);
    course.value = '';
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

}
```

Comment: i go with this step but error changed anther , it comes after put value in input tag

Comment: ContentComponent.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at ContentComponent.webpackJsonp../src/app/component/content/content.component.ts.ContentComponent.add (content.component.ts:26)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ContentComponent.html:5)
    at handleEvent (core.es5.js:11998)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.es5.js:13467)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.es5.js:13055)
    at dispatchEvent (core.es5.js:8614)
    at core.es5.js:9228
    at platform-browser.es5.js:2648
    at platform-browser.es5.js:3317

Comment: `(keyup.enter)="add()` you aren't passing anything into the function, so your `course` is undefined. maybe you want something like this? html: `<input type="text" value="someValue" (keyup.enter)="add()">`  function: `add(){
    this.courses.push(this.someValue);
   this.someValue = '';
  }`